# What are the gas limitations for a certain message call?

Tags: solidity, gas

Can anyone explain this to me:

"*Calls are limited to a depth of 1024, which means that for more complex operations, loops should be preferred over recursive calls. Furthermore, only 63/64th of the gas can be forwarded in a message call, which causes a depth limit of a little less than 1000 in practice.*"

This comes from solidity docs. Does the last mean that there can be no transaction with 1000 gas or more? Why and how do loops prevent a big amount of gas from being spent?

Source: [https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html#:~:text=are%20fully%20synchronous.-,Calls,-are%20limited%20to](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html#:%7E:text=are%20fully%20synchronous.-,Calls,-are%20limited%20to)

Comment: It means that at the time the block gas limit was around 6.5M, so after 1000 call the max available gas would have been `6.5*10^6 * (63/64)^1000 < 1`, so it didn't reach above 1000 calls.